# The target "DeleteCurrentDeployment" does not exist in the project.

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-cloud-services

I had do downgrade to azure sdk 2.2 for a project. And after installing everything I still cannot compile the solution containing a cloud service and I receive error The target "DeleteCurrentDeployment" does not exist in the project. When I click it points to Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin I trying installing and uninstalling again but nothing works..

Comment: I am using VIsual Studio 2013.

Comment: it looks like some package is missing, like the azure emulator

Comment: I think you should remove both the azure sdk and azure tools for visual studio, and then re-install